# c# how do I loop through all headers of HttpRequestHeaders

Tags: c#, .net, header

I want to loop through all headers of `HttpRequestHeaders` of `HttpRequestMessage`.

I am just migrating my code from `HttpWebRequest` to `HttpClient`.
With `HttpWebRequest` I used following code to loop through its `WebHeaderCollection`:

```
StringBuilder headers_ = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string key in headers.AllKeys)
{
    headers_.Append(key).Append(':').Append(headers[key]).Append(' ');
}
headers_.Length--;
```

but `HttpRequestHeaders` doesn't have AllKeys method. It only has `GetValues(string name)` which only retrieves one specified header.

```
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://postman-echo.com/post"),
    Headers = {
        { "header1", "aa" },
        { "header2", "bb" },
    },
    Content = new StringContent("hi=aa")
}
```

How do I programmatically retrieve pairs of { "header1", "aa" }, { "header2", "bb" } from `requestMessage`?

Comment: Cant you use `entries` method?

Comment: Entries doesn't exist https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/hh193710(v%3Dvs.118)

Comment: oh I forgot to clearly state it is c#. Sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alright it was simpler than I expected.

```
foreach (var header in httpRequestMessage.Headers)
{
    string headerName = header.Key;
    string headerContent = string.Join(",", header.Value.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As headers are properties from class HttpRequestHeaders, you need reflection to enumerate them, here a code snippet that enumerates headers.

```
var headers = new HttpClient().DefaultRequestHeaders;

PropertyInfo[] properties = headers.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var property in properties)
      Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this returns some 30 default headers. I want to loop through my headers of HttpRequestMessage. I will update my question with more specific code.